# Fill a Swing table with some data from MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I need to fill a Swing table with some data from MySQL DB. The problem is that the table does not display all the columns (i.e. `a.aircraftType` and `b.aircraftCategory`). In Debug mode I checked that the query returns correct data. So, why finally some columns are not displayed?

```
    private JTable tbArrivals;
    private QueryTableModelFS mdArrivals;


    mdArrivals = new QueryTableModelFS();       
    tbArrivals = new JTable(mdArrivals);

    private void fillArrivals() {
            mdArrivals.setHost(url); mdArrivals.setDB(db); mdArrivals.setLogin(login); mdArrivals.setPassw(passw);

            String query;

            query = "SELECT a.id,a.flightNum_arr,a.from_ICAO,a.ETA,a.pkId,a.aircraftType,b.aircraftCategory " +
                    "FROM flightschedule a, aircrafts b " +
                    "WHERE a.aircraftType = b.aircraftType;";
            mdArrivals.setQuery(query);
    }


  public void setQuery(String query) {
    cache = new Vector();
    try {
      // Execute the query and store the result set and its metadata
      Connection con = getConnection();
      Statement statement = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
      ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
      colCount = meta.getColumnCount();
      // Rebuild the headers array with the new column names
      headers = new String[colCount];
      for (int h = 1; h <= colCount; h++) {
        headers[h - 1] = meta.getColumnName(h);
      }
      while (rs.next()) {
        String[] record = new String[colCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
          record[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
        }
        cache.addElement(record);
      }
      fireTableChanged(null);         
      rs.close();
      if (con.getAutoCommit() != false) {
        con.close();
      }         
    } catch (Exception e) {
      cache = new Vector();
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I would recommend using [`ResultSetTableModel`](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cis5100/examples/ch25/Fig25_28_31/ResultSetTableModel.java) which will handle all the trouble for you.

Comment: Are you certain you added both the table and the table header to your container (or used a scroll pane). See [Adding a table to a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show) in the `JTable` tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what how your TableModel works (it looks like you might be using the DefaultTableModel),  but I would suggest using Vectors instead of Arrays to get the data from your ResultSet. Right now your code is very confusing. In one loop you are using (i - 1) to access the data. In the next loop you are using (i + 1). I know the reason is because Arrays are 0 based and the ResultSet is 1 based.

When you use a Vector your loops can just start with 1 and then you just use the addElement() method to add the data to the Vector so your code is not concerned with matching indexes.

See `Table From Database Example` in [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/).